# MS SQL вывод данных по условию из одного столбца

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Как можно вывести значения где соблюдена комбинация Role_id (1,2,3,4) для r_atr_id

[image: Тестовая таблица]

Пытался сделать так

```
Select * from Table where Role_id in (1,2,3,4)
```

но выводит всех

Comment: Покажите, каким должен быть результат? Не понимаю, что значит "соблюдена комбинация"

Comment: допустим пришел запрос на столбец Role_id, где равен 1,2,3,4. И должен быть произведен поиск r_atr_id где есть данные числа. Как бы r_atr_id это вариант комбинации. Получается результат при данной комбинации должен вывести r_atr_id = 1

Comment: я все еще ничего не понял. Дополните вопрос правильным результатом вывода и более точным объяснением.

Comment: в данной таблице два варианта (r_atr_id) с комбинациями (1,2,3,4) и (1,2,3). При вводе данных (1,2,3,4) он должен вывести первый вариант а при вводе (1,2,3) второй вариант. Т.е. вывести при первом случае r_atr_id - 1, а во втором 2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r_atr_id FROM (
 SELECT 
   tt.r_atr_id,
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + t.Role_id
          FROM [Table] t    
          WHERE t.id = tt.id    
          ORDER BY t.Role_id
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') comb
 FROM [Table] tt
 GROUP BY tt.r_atr_id, tt.Role_id
 ORDER BY 1
) WHERE comb = '1,2,3,4';
```